# How to upload attachments in browser tests using Appium?

Tags: google-chrome, appium, python-appium

I am trying to automate a test case in Chrome where I would like to upload an attachment to an email. I use desiredCaps['browserName'] = 'Chrome'. While clicking attachments in email, it opens the Documents in the phone, but I am unable to detect the elements in the Documents screen.

[image: Documents folder in the phone]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.If you are using ruby

This basically goes into the directory called `screenshots` and finds the second picture or the document that is visible inside the directory

```
find_element(id: "screenshots").find_element(class: "android.widget.ImageView[2]").click
end
```

This captures the first document/picture visible in the gallery

```
find_element(id: "").find_element(class: "android.widget.ImageView").click
```

You can modify it as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks Mrityunjeyan. I think the problem here is initially driver is set to use the Chrome browser (I believe it is the webdriver) and then the Document attach screen which comes up is in native android. So webdriver is not able to reach to the native android screen. So was just checking if there is a way to switch to native android driver.

Comment: What error does it display when you are trying to detect the documents screen?

Comment: It just times out and says that the element is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud change context to from Chromium to 'NATIVE_APP' appium doc about it (http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/) and use Touch Actions for choose you file

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you can use the below code to switch context.

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles(); 
for (final String contextName : contextNames) { 
if (contextName.contains("NATIVE")) { 
driver.context(contextName); 
System.out.println("Switched to Native Context"); 
} 
}
```

in Python you can try something like this

```
contextNames = driver.contexts
for aContext in contextNames
if "NATIVE" in aContext:
driver.switch_to.context(aContext)
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).